# Can I use a greenest pixel or a no clouds Sentinel 2 for NDVI analysis?

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, ndvi, sentinel-2

Can I use a greenest pixel or a no clouds Sentinel 2 for NDVI analysis? I want to use it for extract spectral signature.
And now that I´m asking about it, I want to know if I can work classification based on spectral signature in Google Earth Engine.

Note: Sorry if I have a bad redaction, my native language is note english.

Answer (score 1):

To youre first question:
Yes it is possible to derive NDVI by Sentinel-2 image.

Here are some useful links to get started with Earth Engine and Sentinel-2

1. [Description of Dataset inside GEE - Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-1C](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2)
2. [Tutorial: NDVI, Mapping a Function over a Collection, Quality Mosaicking](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_06)
3. [GEE Script example for Sentinel-2 Cloud Masking](https://code.earthengine.google.com/973ccbf1ddeead27c847b57ad2bacf5c)
4. [Other GIS Stackexchange Questions related to GEE, Sentinel-2 and NDVI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ndvi%20sentinel%202%20earth%20engine)